# libiconv and MacOS

Tags: gcc, osx-lion, iconv, libiconv

I am trying to compile GCC 4.5.1 in Mac OS X Lion.

I have a problem with libiconv. First it complained about undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, which were: _iconv, _iconv_open and _iconv_close. I found out that MacPorts version of libiconv rename those to: _libiconv, _libiconv_open and _libiconv_close. So I linked to the Mac OS native libiconv in /usr/lib instead of the MacPorts library in /opt/local/lib.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_iconv", referenced from:
  _convert_using_iconv in libcpp.a(charset.o)
  __nl_find_msg in libintl.a(dcigettext.o)
 (maybe you meant: __cpp_destroy_iconv, _cpp_init_iconv )
"_iconv_close", referenced from:
  __cpp_destroy_iconv in libcpp.a(charset.o)
  __cpp_convert_input in libcpp.a(charset.o)
  __nl_free_domain_conv in libintl.a(loadmsgcat.o)
"_iconv_open", referenced from:
  _init_iconv_desc in libcpp.a(charset.o)
  __nl_init_domain_conv in libintl.a(loadmsgcat.o)
```

However, after doing that, I tried to rebuild it from the beginning (cleaning and everything), but then it complained at a different point about undefined symbols, but this time _libiconv, _libiconv_open and _libiconv_close.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
    _identifier_to_locale in libbackend.a(pretty-print.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
    _identifier_to_locale in libbackend.a(pretty-print.o)
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
    _identifier_to_locale in libbackend.a(pretty-print.o)
```

Is there any idea about how I can deal with this? I have found some solutions uninstalling libiconv from MacPorts, but I don't want to do it, as I have many ports depending on it.

Comment: how did you solve it finally?

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by:

```
$ sudo port -f deactivate libiconv
$ ...build my project...
$ sudo port activate libiconv
```

There's probably a better way but I'm not using GCC directly, so this helps as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this by including two libiconv from both `/usr/lib` and `/opt/local/lib`. This is a hacky way to solve, if anyone has better solution, please post. Suppose `[gcc-src]` is the source directory of gcc. What I did is as following:

1. In `/usr/lib`, *copy* `libiconv.*` as `libiconv1.*`
2. Go to `[gcc-src]/gcc/Makefile.in`
   change
        `LIBINTL = @LIBINTL@`
   to 
        `LIBINTL = @LIBINTL@ -L/opt/local/lib -liconv -L/usr/lib -liconv1`
3. Configure by: `CC=gcc-mp-4.7 CXX=g++-mp-4.7 ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --with-gmp=/opt/local --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-checking=release —prefix=[gcc-src]`     <- must be absolute address. I use a macport-made gcc and g++. Maybe using gcc and g++ from system work too.
4. `make`
5. `make install`
   The binary will be at `[gcc-src]/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `make clean` didn't actually remove `libbackend.a` from the build directory; you were still trying to link with the old version of your code compiled against MacPorts. Manually running `rm libbackend.a` (or `make distclean` or `make spotless` or whatever is supposed to really clean everything up) probably fixed the problem, right?

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old thread, the solution below might help someone searching historic questions for help. It is a simple one-line command that will fix the problem using sed to *correct* all of the iconv function references.

```
$ tar xf gcc-6.4.0.tar.gz
$ cd gcc=6.4.0
$ # convert iconv(..)       --> _libiconv(..)
$ # convert iconv_open(..)  --> _libiconv_open(..)
$ # convert iconv_close(..) --> _libiconv_close(..)
$ LC_ALL=C time \
    sed -i.bak -e 's@\(iconv[^\(]*(\)@_lib\1@g' \
    $(grep -l -r 'iconv[^\(]*(' . 2>/dev/null)
```

I used the above solution for this project: https://github.com/jlinoff/gcc-6.4.0-boost-1.66.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when Building GCC 6.3.0 stage 1 using Xcode 10 on Mojave.

Comment: This did work to compile git (and thanks, it was getting frustrating) but needed a slight modification to get it to work:

First, point explicitly to your iconv dir.
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/git-2.23.0 --with-iconv=/usr/local/iconv

Then modify the source like above but "@_lib\1g" needed to be "@lib\1g" for me (no underscore).

Also, the command above goes one change too far so change this one line back
in compat/precompose_utf8.c: turn "libiconv_ibp cp' back to "iconv_ibp"

Comment: Actually, it bothered me so much to be changing git's source code just to address an iconv lib error that I dove into this further and resolved it entirely with Makefile changes to point things at the right version of the iconv lib. I created [a post to explain why this is happening with iconv and how to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734434/libiconv-or-iconv-undefined-symbol-on-mac-osx/57734435).

Answer (score 1):

New answer for old question. The short answer is you have multiple iconv libs on your system. There are a ton of related questions on stackoverflow that don't really answer the underlying problem, so I created an answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734434/libiconv-or-iconv-undefined-symbol-on-mac-osx/57734435) that explains what's happening in depth and how to resolve.