# I cannot execute stack setup because of iconv error

Tags: linux, haskell

When I installed stack by brew and setup for haskell learning, error was occurred

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/stack-sanity-check-51e69d22a73355e8/Main.hs, /private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/stack-sanity-check-51e69d22a73355e8/Main.o )
Linking /private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/stack-sanity-check-51e69d22a73355e8/Main ...
Standard error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv in libHSbase-4.12.0.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding1_closure, _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding1_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding15_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_info , _hs_iconv_open , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding12_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding12_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding13_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding13_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding14_bytes , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding15_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding3_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_closure , _hs_iconv , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_bytes , _hs_iconv_close , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding5_closure )
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_open in libHSbase-4.12.0.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_open)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_close in libHSbase-4.12.0.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_close)
  "_locale_charset", referenced from:
      _localeEncoding in libHSbase-4.12.0.0.a(PrelIOUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

`libiconv.2.4.0.dylib` , `libiconv.2.dylib` and `libiconv.dylib` are in 
 `/usr/lib` directory

my Mac os version is `mac OS Mojave 10.14`

```
$ iconv --version
iconv (GNU libiconv 1.15)
Copyright (C) 2000-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Bruno Haible.

$ which iconv
/Users/{myAccountName}/.pyenv/shims/iconv
```

Maybe I think `which iconv` 's output must be `/usr/lib`, but it is not. That's why I wrote the `which iconv` callback and ask someone who knows how to change `iconv` 's callee.

But it is my guess. It was probably not the reason of the error. So, I also ask the other reason of the error and how to fix.

Sorry for not fluent english.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619600/libiconv-and-macos

Comment: Have you tried adding `extra-lib-dirs: [/usr/lib]` to `stack.yaml` ?

Comment: ty! I'll try it.